# AWS Load Balancer, Sticky Sessions and Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, http-headers, session-cookies, amazon-elb

I am currently using an `AWS ELB` with `Application-Controlled Session` Stickiness which has `PHPSESSID` assigned as the cookie name.

I managed to get the session cookie `PHPSESSID` on android in the HTTP response header. In order to maintain this stickiness and direct subsequent requests to the target web server, do I have to send the cookie from android back to the web server? Because the load balances has to look at HTTP header requests coming from android in order to determine which server it should direct subsequent requests.

Comment: Yes you have to send the cookie back with every request in order for sticky sessions to work.

Comment: As Mark stated - yes, you need to persist the cookies with every request.

Elastic Load Balancer does not support session persistence by IP address.

There are [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662349/cookie-management-with-java-urlconnection) StackOverflow questions covering persisting cookies in Android applications -- so it'd be good to start there.