# What does it mean by VM wide cookie management?

Tags: android, cookies, httpurlconnection, android-sharedpreferences, android-cookiemanager

I am learning to store `cookies` in Android and came across several ways of implementing it. One of them being the use of `CookieManager and CookieStore`.

As I was going through Android docs, I came across the following statement:

> To establish and maintain a potentially long-lived session between
>   client and server, HttpURLConnection includes an extensible cookie
>   manager. Enable VM-wide cookie management using CookieHandler and
>   CookieManager:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();  
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

I don't understand the meaning of `VM-wide cookie management`. I know that VM means `Virtual Machine`.

**My Interpretations:**

1. ***One way I interpreted it is, creating a `CookieManager`and passing it to `setDefault()` makes it available throughout the application. Hence, I tried the following to test it.***

   ```
    URL url = new URL("http://something.com");
    URI uri=new URI("http://something.com");
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    cks=urlConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");  
    //cks is a String
    cookieManager=new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    HttpCookie hc=new HttpCookie("Cookie1",cks);
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(uri,hc);
    cks1=cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();
    //cks1 is another String
   ```

   I set `cks and cks1` to `TextViews` and it printed cookie `content/value` as expected. Based on my interpretation, I tried `cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();` in another activity but it didn't recognise the object which means it is out of scope and not accessible. Also, created a new `CookieManager` and tried to get the cookies but it returned `null`. So, I assume this interpretation of VM-wide being accessible across activities is incorrect.
2. ***Second Interpretation was Cookies will be automatically stored when `CookieManager` is set up. I got it from a solution to another question on SO: [Cookie management with Java URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662349/cookie-management-with-java-urlconnection/29663011#comment85627325_29663011)***

One of the statements in the solution that suggested so:

> When HttpURLConnection receives a cookie from the server the
>   CookieManager will receive the cookie and store it. Future requests to
>   the same server will automatically send the previously set cookies.

I removed `cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(uri,hc);` to test it and discovered that cookies are not stored automatically. So, that interpretation fails too.

### **ANOTHER DOUBT THAT HAUNTS ME:**

Most of the solutions to storing cookies for later use suggests using `SharedPreferences`. The thing that haunts me is all of them stores cookies in `CookieManager` initially and later moves it to `SharedPreferences`. Why not use `SharedPreferences` directly?

For example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://something.com");
 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 cks=urlConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); 
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
 Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.putString("cookie_name", cks);  // Saving cookie
 editor.commit();
```

So what is the point of using `CookieManager` and then moving it to `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: "I tried cookieManager...; in another activity but it didn't recognise the object which means it is out of scope and not accessible" - You got a fresh instance or you tried accessing it across activites? Any exception?

Comment: I tried accessing it across activities(same object).

Comment: And you got a NPE presumably? or is it a static field?

Comment: It is a `static field` :D

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not clear what "didn't recognise the object" means. Post the error you are seeing

Comment: What I mean is it doesn't recognise the object any differently. Accessing `cookieManager` in new activity works even without `CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);`. Also, it is only recognised in another activity when it is defined as `static`. I am trying to understand what exactly `CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);` is doing and what is meant by VM wide cookie management..

Comment: once it is set you should be able to use CookieHandler.getDefault() - you should not need any static objects

Comment: Oh. That is what I was missing. I get it now. Is this `CookieManager` common for all the apps or just the app it is defined in? And does it exist when I restart the app? What I was trying to do is access the same object everywhere and expected it to work. Didn't know there was a `getDefault()` function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More details on Android's cookie management framework can be found [in this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html), but in short, you only need to `setDefault()` once. In subsequent calls you can use `CookieHandler.getDefault()` and you supply the cookies to the sessions as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/984830)

Using the default implementations you'll only be able to access cookies from your own application.

In simplest terms an Android VM is the layer that translates your application bytecode into machine code and it is one VM per application - so VM-Wide means Application scoped.

SharedPrefs can be used to persist cookies between sessions, although this should be rarely useful (just my opinion)

Comment: Got it :D Thanks a lot, Nick. `One VM per application` completes it. Also, is the `default CookieManager` saved and restored on restarting the app or is it a new instance everytime?

Comment: I believe you need to set the instance each time

Comment: Even with `CookieManager`, I will have to read the `headers` and store in them manually using `cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(uri,hc);`, right? Or is it done automatically?

Comment: Yes you still need to, it's just a little simpler (no need to worry about object format). I'll reword my answer because thats a mistake

Comment: @MathewsMathai I see you don't have the benefactor badge - so if you are not aware, you have to manually award bounties (if you are going to)

Comment: Done :D Thought it was automatic.

Comment: I think lots of people believe that, but it's not - if you get an answer that scores highly but don't award it, the system awards half